# Unable to edit Contacts in Google Contacts that have a specific Label?

Tags: google-contacts

I appear to have a problem with a *corrupt*(?) *label* in Google Contacts that is assigned to many contacts. Everything was OK when last edited my contacts about a week ago (when I specifically edited a bunch of contacts with this label).

- I'm unable to edit any contact that has this label. I get the error "Problem with updating contact". None of the reasons given in the "[learn more](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/148779)" link to the help docs applies to my situation (regarding "limits").

  UPDATE: I can seemingly edit the contact on Android/phone and get no error. However, it doesn't seem to be sync'd, unlike edits to other contacts without this label. The edit does seem to remain on the phone.
- I seem to be able to edit any other contact that does not have this one label.
- I can remove this label from the contact. Then successfully edit and save the contact. But if I then try to add the label back again I get the error: "Can't edit labels" and the label is not added (no "learn more" link and I can't find much about this particular error).
- If I try to rename the label I also get the error: "Can't edit labels" and the label is not renamed. (I can rename *other* labels OK.)

Are there any fixes for this without having to remove and recreate a new label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve this "corrupt" label. The problem still persists - the "corrupt" label remains.

However, as a workaround, I was able to create a "new" label and assign the same contacts to the new label (and removing the "corrupt" label) en masse.

1. Create a "new" label.
2. Select all contacts with the "corrupt" label (option on the *toolbar*).
3. Select "Manage Labels" (icon on the *toolbar*) and in the dropdown list of labels, unselect the "corrupt" label and select the "new" label and hit [Apply].

Unfortunately, the "corrupt" label (now with 0 contacts assigned) cannot be deleted as I get the error: "Problem with deleting label".

And I'm unable to rename the "new" label to the same name as the "corrupt" label as (you might expect) I get the error: "Label name already exists".

I cannot now add any contacts to the "corrupt" label. It seems this "corrupt" label is just going to remain, a *pollutant* amongst my nicely ordered labels!